# Configure specific SFSB stateful-timeout in standalone.xml (JBOSS)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

For my JEE 3.1 application I have a SFSB for which I have set a specific timeout. I need to have easy access to this value to allow it to be easily configurable.

First I had the annotation in my SFSB class:

```
@StatefulTimeout(value = 2, unit = TimeUnit.HOURS)
```

This works as expected. But I need this value to be (easily) configurable. Therefore I removed the annotation and placed the following xml in my ejb-jar.xml. Again this works as expected.

```
<session>
    <ejb-name>MyStatefulSessionBeanName</ejb-name>
    <ejb-class>foo.bar.MyStatefulSessionBean</ejb-class>
    <session-type>Stateful</session-type>
    <stateful-timeout>
        <timeout>2</timeout>
        <unit>Hours</unit>
    </stateful-timeout>
</session>
```

But the ejb-jar.xml is packaged in a .jar which is within my .ear application deployment. Therefore my question is, can this setting be placed in the standalone.xml file of jboss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this without an application restart.

If that is OK then you can define a system property in your standalone.xml. I recommend using the CLI or the admin console for this purpose.

You can then use property values in your ejb-jar.xml:

```
<stateful-timeout>
    <timeout>${my.session.timeout.value}</timeout>
    <unit>${my.session.timeout.units}</unit>
</stateful-timeout>
```

The property values can then be updated via the web console or CLI and your application restarted.

Comment: Note that for this to work you need to set 'spec-descriptor-property-replacement' to 'true' in the standalone.xml. You will also lose Java EE compliance.

Comment: Thanks Steve and Barry, this solved my issue. Restarting the server is not an issue for me.